# Errors when attempting Playback on OpenMeetings

Tags: ffmpeg, mp4

I am new to Linux, so if I am just overlooking something that should be obvious or if I'm directing this in the wrong place, please don't judge me too hard I just am stumped.

I have just finished installing OpenMeetings (3.2.1) onto Ubuntu 16.04 using the [instructions](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/OPENMEETINGS/Tutorials+for+installing+OpenMeetings+and+Tools?preview=/27838216/68719905/Installation%20OpenMeetings%203.2.1%20on%20Ubuntu%2016.04%20LTS.pdf%20%22instructions) provided almost verbatim. On both instances of the install I've gotten the below error when attempting to playback any recording from any conference room.

```
The have been errors while processing the recording    


Recording file is not found


Exit value

Conversion messages

0 process: generateSampleAudio
command: /usr/bin/sox /opt/red5321/webapps/openmeetings/streams/hibernate/one_second.wav /opt/red5321/webapps/openmeetings/streams/7/rec_3_stream_e7ebdbfa-0716-4173-bd7e-797cbdc22d91_2017_04_04_09_42_26_FINAL_WAVE.wav pad 0 9.0 
exception: null
error: 
exitValue: 0
out: 

1 process: generate MP4
command: /usr/bin/ffmpeg -y -itsoffset 00:00:01.000 -i /opt/red5321/webapps/openmeetings/streams/7/rec_3_stream_e7ebdbfa-0716-4173-bd7e-797cbdc22d91_2017_04_04_09_42_26.flv -i /opt/red5321/webapps/openmeetings/streams/7/rec_3_stream_e7ebdbfa-0716-4173-bd7e-797cbdc22d91_2017_04_04_09_42_26_FINAL_WAVE.wav -c:v h264 -crf 24 -pix_fmt yuv420p -preset medium -profile:v baseline -c:a libfaac -c:a libfdk_aac -ar 22050 -b:a 32k -s 960x768 /opt/red5321/webapps/openmeetings/streams/hibernate/caf73e1d-4536-4ca2-a709-2efc7228ac48.mp4 
exception: null
error: ffmpeg version 2.8.11-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2017 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 5.4.0 (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.4) 20160609
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version=0ubuntu0.16.04.1 --build-suffix=-ffmpeg --toolchain=hardened --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --incdir=/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu --cc=cc --cxx=g++ --enable-gpl --enable-shared --disable-stripping --disable-decoder=libopenjpeg --disable-decoder=libschroedinger --enable-avresample --enable-avisynth --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librtmp --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzvbi --enable-openal --enable-opengl --enable-x11grab --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libiec61883 --enable-libzmq --enable-frei0r --enable-libx264 --enable-libopencv
  libavutil      54. 31.100 / 54. 31.100
  libavcodec     56. 60.100 / 56. 60.100
  libavformat    56. 40.101 / 56. 40.101
  libavdevice    56.  4.100 / 56.  4.100
  libavfilter     5. 40.101 /  5. 40.101
  libavresample   2.  1.  0 /  2.  1.  0
  libswscale      3.  1.101 /  3.  1.101
  libswresample   1.  2.101 /  1.  2.101
  libpostproc    53.  3.100 / 53.  3.100
Input #0, flv, from '/opt/red5321/webapps/openmeetings/streams/7/rec_3_stream_e7ebdbfa-0716-4173-bd7e-797cbdc22d91_2017_04_04_09_42_26.flv':
  Metadata:
    server          : Red5
    creationdate    : Tue Apr 04 09:42:35 PDT 2017
    canSeekToEnd    : true
    noaudiocodec    : 0
  Duration: 00:00:08.80, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 2348 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Video: flashsv, bgr24, 960x768, 2347 kb/s, 10 fps, 10 tbr, 1k tbn, 1k tbc
Guessed Channel Layout for  Input Stream #1.0 : mono
Input #1, wav, from '/opt/red5321/webapps/openmeetings/streams/7/rec_3_stream_e7ebdbfa-0716-4173-bd7e-797cbdc22d91_2017_04_04_09_42_26_FINAL_WAVE.wav':
  Duration: 00:00:10.00, bitrate: 705 kb/s
    Stream #1:0: Audio: pcm_s16le ([1][0][0][0] / 0x0001), 44100 Hz, 1 channels, s16, 705 kb/s
Unknown encoder 'libfdk_aac'

exitValue: 1
out: 

1 process: generate preview JPG
command: /usr/bin/ffmpeg -y -i /opt/red5321/webapps/openmeetings/streams/hibernate/caf73e1d-4536-4ca2-a709-2efc7228ac48.mp4 -vcodec mjpeg -vframes 100 -an -f rawvideo -s 960x768 /opt/red5321/webapps/openmeetings/streams/hibernate/caf73e1d-4536-4ca2-a709-2efc7228ac48.jpg 
exception: null
error: ffmpeg version 2.8.11-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2017 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 5.4.0 (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.4) 20160609
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version=0ubuntu0.16.04.1 --build-suffix=-ffmpeg --toolchain=hardened --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --incdir=/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu --cc=cc --cxx=g++ --enable-gpl --enable-shared --disable-stripping --disable-decoder=libopenjpeg --disable-decoder=libschroedinger --enable-avresample --enable-avisynth --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librtmp --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzvbi --enable-openal --enable-opengl --enable-x11grab --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libiec61883 --enable-libzmq --enable-frei0r --enable-libx264 --enable-libopencv
  libavutil      54. 31.100 / 54. 31.100
  libavcodec     56. 60.100 / 56. 60.100
  libavformat    56. 40.101 / 56. 40.101
  libavdevice    56.  4.100 / 56.  4.100
  libavfilter     5. 40.101 /  5. 40.101
  libavresample   2.  1.  0 /  2.  1.  0
  libswscale      3.  1.101 /  3.  1.101
  libswresample   1.  2.101 /  1.  2.101
  libpostproc    53.  3.100 / 53.  3.100
/opt/red5321/webapps/openmeetings/streams/hibernate/caf73e1d-4536-4ca2-a709-2efc7228ac48.mp4: No such file or directory

exitValue: 1
out:
```

The folder paths referenced in the error output all have read/write/execute permissions applied to them.

Answer (score 1):

## `Unknown encoder 'libfdk_aac'`

#### Problem

Your command is attempting to choose an audio encoder with `-c:a libfaac -c:a libfdk_aac`. There are a few issues with this:

- The command is listing two encoders for one output. Only one should be listed. In this case the second one will supersede the first, so libfaac will be ignored.
- Your ffmpeg does not have `--enable-libfaac` or `--enable-libfdk_aac` in the `ffmpeg` configure line, so these encoders are not available. That is why you get `Unknown encoder 'libfdk_aac'`.
- libfaac support has been removed, so you should avoid it if you want to use a modern and up-to-date `ffmpeg`.

#### Solution

Remove `-c:a libfaac -c:a libfdk_aac` and the native FFmpeg AAC encoder will automatically be chosen. Alternatively, you can use `-c:a aac` to manually choose the native FFmpeg AAC encoder.

If you're using an old, outdated `ffmpeg` then you'll need to add `-strict experimental` to your command to enable the native FFmpeg AAC encoder. However, it's recommended to update your `ffmpeg` instead because the native FFmpeg AAC encoder was greatly improved.

You can update to a new `ffmpeg` by [downloading](https://johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/) it and moving it to `/usr/local/bin` or `~/bin` and pointing your script to it.

---

## `No such file or directory`

This is straightforward: check that the input exists and the path to the input is correct.

---

## Better command

Your command to generate a JPG isn't very good:

Change:

```
-vcodec mjpeg -vframes 100 -an -f rawvideo -s 960x768
```

To:

```
-vframes 1 -ss 1 -vf scale=960:-1
```

- You generally don't need `-vcodec` or `-f` for image outputs: the output file name will automatically determine the encoder and container format.
- `-vframes 100` will output 100 frames, but you list a single file name for the output. Use `-vframes 1` instead.
- `-an` isn't needed for image outputs.
- `-f rawvideo` outputs rawvideo, but you want a JPG. Remove it or use `-f image2` if you need to manually declare the output format (such as if the output name is a variable).
- The [scale filter](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#scale) is better than `-s` in every way.